# setOnClickListener - how to pass in AdapterView<?> in onClick

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

Update: I revised my original question because it was too vague.

I just implemented a RecyclerView and now I want to make each item clickable,  so that when I click on an item it will will take me to DetailsActivity (for phone and tablet) where I can find out more information about the item.

I was able to do this prior to implementing a recyclerview because all I had is a gridview where I call  mGridView.setOnItemClickListener.

Here is the code prior to recyclerview:

```
public class BookFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

   ....
   .....

    public interface CallbackInterface {
        /**
         * DetailFragmentCallback for when an item has been selected.
         */
        public void onItemSelected(Uri bookUri);
    }


    ....
    .....


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


        // initialize our BookAdapter
        mBookAdapter = new BookAdapter(getActivity(), null, 0, CURSOR_LOADER_ID);
        // initialize mGridView to the GridView in fragment_main.xml
        mGridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Book_grid);
        // set mGridView adapter to our CursorAdapter
        mGridView.setAdapter(mBookAdapter);

        // make each item clickable
        mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                int uriId = position + 1;

                Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(BookContentProvider.Book.CONTENT_URI,
                        uriId);

                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                if (cursor != null) {

                    ((CallbackInterface) getActivity())
                            .onItemSelected(BookContentProvider.Book.withId(cursor.getLong(0))); // getlong(0) gets the row ID
                }
            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }
.....

}
```

Now that I have recyclerview it looks like I cannot longer call mGridView.setOnItemClickListener, as Recyclerview does not have this method. It looks like I can call setOnClickListener but I'm not sure how I  can implement that  in my BookCursorAdapter:

Here is my code BookCursorAdapter:

```
public class BookCursorAdapter extends CursorRecyclerViewAdapter<BookCursorAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = BookCursorAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private static Context mContext;
    private ViewHolder mVh;


    public BookCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        public final ImageView imageView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            mView = view;
            imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_book_imageview);

        }

    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_Book, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(itemView);
        mVh = vh;
        return vh;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Cursor cursor) {

        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);

        int imageIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(BookColumns.COLUMN_IMAGEPATH);
        String image = cursor.getString(imageIndex);
        if (image != null) {
            Picasso.with(viewHolder.imageView.getContext())
                    .load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w400/" + image)
                    .resize(600, 800)  
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(viewHolder.imageView);
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.VH> {

private Cursor cursor;

public MyAdapter(Cursor c) {
    cursor = c;
}

// View Holder
public static class VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView _textView;
    public ImageView _icon;

    public VH(View v) {
        super(v);
        _textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        _icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
    }

}


@Override
public MyAdapter.VH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // inflate the layout and create a new ViewHolder with it.
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.baseitem, parent, false);
    return new VH(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final VH holder, int position) {
    // This is called whenever the RecyclerView needs to bind data to the viewholders.
    // This will happen continuously whilst scrolling.
    // Viewholders scrolled off screen are likely to be reused.
    // so make sure you reset any values in it to the defaults.

    cursor.moveToPosition(position);

    holder._textView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MyStringData")));
    holder._icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icv_arrow_up);

    holder._icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("TAG", holder._textView.getText().toString() + " was pressed");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cursor.getCount();
}

}
```

Comment: Hi @Kuffs thanks for replying. I'm not sure how I can do that as I currently pass in a Cursor in my onBindViewHolder method like this:  public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Cursor cursor){
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);


        int imageIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(BookColumns.COLUMN_IMAGEPATH);
        String image = cursor.getString(imageIndex);
     
        }

    }

Comment: My answer is an example only. You would tailor it to your specific needs. My point was that you are setting the listener in the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks @Kuffs. just tried to implement your suggestion but I'm a bit loss because I still cannot figure out how to return a Cursor. As in my previous code I return a cursor bcause I call parent.getItemAtPosition like this:    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(getAdapterPosition());

Comment: Does my edit help? Sorry if there are mistakes in it as I typed it directly but it should give you an idea about what I am suggesting which is to pass the cursor into the adapter via its constructor and then manipulate the data inside the adapter.

Comment: hi @Kuffs many thanks for providing more details. I tried that but it did not work because its asking me to implement onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Cursor cursor) method.  I provided more context and updated my question to make it more clear this time.

Comment: OK. You didn't say you were using a custom adapter. My method still works but you need to amend it to suit the custom class. I would recommend you learn how to use the standard classes first though before you attempt to customise them.

Comment: Thanks @Kuffs, apologies if I forgot to mention my custom adapter yesterday. I tried your method where I  pass in the cursor in the constructor and I assigned it to mCursor.  in my onBindViewHolder I have this but it can't resolved getactivity():        

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCursor = getCursor();
                if (mCursor != null) {
                    ((CallbackTwoPane)getActivity())
                            .onItemSelected(BookContentProvider.Book.withId(mCursor.getLong(0))); // getlong(0) gets the row ID
                }
            }
        });